# How to view a .WRL file?

Tags: 3d-modeling

I need to open a .WRL file on either Ubuntu 16.04 or Windows 10.

Does anyone know how to do this? Cortana3D doesn't seem to work, and I cant find anything for ubuntu that doesn't involve building something from source with outdated instructions.

Comment: Building software is straightforward in most cases, there is no need to be afraid. How did you determine the instructions were out of date? // There are quite some VRML viewers available. Did you try all of them? Do you have any more specific problems than “doesn’t seem to work”?

Comment: Have you tried [FreeWRL](http://freewrl.sourceforge.net/)? "FreeWRL is an X3D/VRML open source viewer for Windows, Linux and Android."

Comment: [qiew](http://www.qiew.org/) works well. No need of admin rights on Windows.

Comment: [FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org/) is nice too.

Answer (score 3):

I have never used these files, but after some googling i came up with this [site](https://web.archive.org/web/20140412054654/http://cic.nist.gov/vrml/vbdetect.html) which lists some vrml/x3d viewers. some people said that the InstantPlayer binaries works for ubuntu, but It wouldnt open some test .wrl i downloaded.

look like [view3dscene](http://castle-engine.sourceforge.net/view3dscene.php) works for some people. On this page you can find the binaries for both 32-bit and 64-bit Ubuntu.

It's a bit ugly, but seems to work for other users. Here is what it looked like for them: 
[image]